# Segmentation fault because of the array size?

Tags: c++

I've been doing a really really simple finite difference code that solves the 1D convection equation.
It seems to work pretty fine but if I increase the size of the arrays that I'm using I get a segmentation fault error. This happens when I reduce the timestep or if I increase the time interval.
The code is

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


int main(){

double xi = 0.0;
double xf = 10.0;
double ti = 0.0;
double tf = 1.0;
```

Time interval, if it is equal to 1 the code works fine.

```
double x,t;
double dt = 0.1;
double dx = 0.1;

int nstep_x = (xf - xi)/dx;
int nstep_t = (tf - ti)/dt;

double f[nstep_x][nstep_t];
double ex[nstep_x][nstep_t];

// Parameters
const double v = 0.05; 
const double D = 0.0001;
const double pi = 3.141592654;

ofstream salida;
salida.open("out");

for (int i = 0 ; i <= nstep_x; i++){
    x = xi + dx*i;
    f[i][0] = 0.5*sin(pi*x); //Initial conditions
    salida << x << " " << 0 << " " << f[i][0] << endl;
    }
    salida << endl;

for (int n = 0; n <= nstep_t ; n++){
        t = ti + n*dt;
        for (int i = 1; i <= nstep_x; i++){
        x = xi + dx*i;
        f[i][n+1] = f[i][n]  - ((v*dt)/(2*dx))*(f[i+1][n] - f[i-1][n]); //CONV|SOC
        ex[i][n] =  0.5*sin(pi*x - v*t);
        salida << x << " " << t << " " << ex[i][n] << " " << f[i][n] << endl;
    }
    salida << endl;
    salida << endl;
  }

  }
```

I think that is not a problem of going out of the array bounds in the loops because the code works for "small" arrays.
I guess that I must be doing something wrong with the array handling but I can't find the error.

Comment: Do note that `f` and `ex` are both variable length arrays and are not standard in C++.

Comment: Assuming your compiler has an extension that allows [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), what are the values of `nstep_x` and `nstep_t` when the crash happens? And you know that the top-index is e.g. `nstep_x - 1` (check your loop conditions)?

Comment: `n <= nstep_t` : I bet you want `n < nstep_t`

Comment: If you can, run `valgrind`. If it's really a write or read error, you'll know.

Comment: I'd say use new for your variable-length arrays.  I can't get your code to compile for this reason, so I can't tell what else might be wrong.

Comment: Stop the VLA stuff and just use `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`.  I wouldn't be surprised if just that alone solves this issue.  `std::vector<std::vector<double>> f(nstep_x, std::vector<double>(nstep_t));` etc..

Comment: *I think that is not a problem of going out of the array bounds in the loops because the code works for "small" arrays* -- That does not prove that you are not going out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues with your code.  One is that you're using variable length arrays (VLA's) which are **not** standard C++.

```
double f[nstep_x][nstep_t];
double ex[nstep_x][nstep_t];
```

This is not valid C++, as arrays must have its size known at compile-time, not run time.

The quick solution is to use `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`:

```
   #include <vector>
   //...
   std::vector<std::vector<double>> f(nstep_x, std::vector<double>(nstep_t));
   std::vector<std::vector<double>> ex = f; // use copy constructor to easily create a copy
```

The above code basically does what your originally did, but has several advantages:

1)  The code is now standard C++, as it uses a standard C++ container class, `std::vector`.

2) You won't get into stack space issues if `nstep_x` and/or `nstep_t` are large values since `std::vector` gets the memory to store its items from the heap.

3) You can check boundary conditions by using `std::vector::at()` if it is suspected that you are accessing the vector out-of-bounds.  You don't have this test if you're using VLA's (or just arrays in general).

It is item 3) that becomes important in attempting to find the errors.

---

If we take your code, change it to using `std::vector`, we see that there **is** a problem with "small arrays", going against what you thought was not an issue.  If we look at this code:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <= nstep_x; i++)
{
    x = xi + dx*i;
    f.at(i).at(0) = 0.5*sin(pi*x); // exception is thrown here
}
```

We see that there is an out-of-bounds condition.  This was detected by using `vector::at()` instead of `[ ]` to access the elements in the vector.  A `std::out_of_range` exception is thrown at the line where `f[i][0]` is being assigned to.

[Here is a live example showing this error](http://ideone.com/xTqD1B).

How do you fix this?  Simply don't go out of bounds by changing the loop:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < nstep_x; i++)
```

You also have boundary condition issues in your other loops:

```
for (int n = 0; n <= nstep_t ; n++)
{
    t = ti + n*dt;
    for (int i = 1; i <= nstep_x; i++)
    {
        x = xi + dx*i;
        f.at(i).at(n+1) = f[i][n] - ((v*dt)/(2*dx))*(f.at(i+1).at(n) - f[i-1][n]); 
        ex.at(i)(n) =  0.5*sin(pi*x - v*t);
    }
}
```

You will see using `at()` that you are accessing the `f` and `ex` vectors out-of-bounds, and thus can diagnose the issue correctly (as the other answers have done).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate  your detailed comment. Now I realized that I had several mistakes on my code. Cheers, Mauro

Answer (score 0):

gdb would help to see where it actually crashes but:

`f[i+1][n]` and `i` grows up to `nstep_x`, but `f` is allocated as `f[nstep_x]`[nstep_t],
so it seems like you'd be accessing `f[nstep_x+1][n]`, but the maximum you can is `f[nstep_x-1][n]`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the reason is not the array size, but the for loops

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <= nstep_x; i++) {
    // ...
    f[i][0] = 0.5*sin(pi*x);
}
```

This is a classic one off error, going one beyond the end of the array. The correct way is

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < nstep_x; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

Note `<` vs `<=`.

---

```
for (int n = 0; n <= nstep_t ; n++) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= nstep_x; i++) {
        // ...
        f[i][n+1] = f[i][n]  - ((v*dt)/(2*dx))*(f[i+1][n] - f[i-1][n]);
    }
}
```

Here too, you have `<=` instead of `<`. Additionally you access indexes at `i + 1` and `n + 1` respectively, which means, you are not one but two steps over the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

When calculating the second time-step, you're referring to `f` at `x=xi` and `t=ti+dt` which wasn't calculated in the first time-step, since `i` runs from 1. There is a similar problem at the other boundary.

You need to specify the spatial boundary conditions for `x=xi` and `x=xf` for all `t` as well as fixing the off-by-one errors noted in the other answers.

To clarify, the convection equation requires boundary conditions to be specified for `f(x=xi,t)` and `f(x=xf, t)`. This is typically either a constant or a prescribed flow rate in the case of an 'insulated' boundary, but other types exist.