# for loop is crashing on big number

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, random, gsl

I have a problem. I have to write a program that counts the collisions of a table of randomly generated numbers (collision test). For example the table [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6] has 3 collisions.

And my problem is that whenever i try to increase number `n` to for example `int n = 5191401;` my program crashes. What is happening? Why does it stop working? I need really big amount of random numbers (like 10^14).

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main (void)
{
    unsigned int seed=10540000;
    gsl_rng * r=gsl_rng_alloc (gsl_rng_minstd);
    gsl_rng_set(r,seed);
    gsl_rng_env_setup();
    int lPrzedzialow=400000000;
    int n = 519140;
    int z,lKolizji=0;
    int lwKomorkach[n-1];
    double dlPrzedzialu=1./(lPrzedzialow);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        lwKomorkach[i]=floor(gsl_rng_uniform (r)/dlPrzedzialu)+1;
    }

    qsort (lwKomorkach, n, sizeof(int), compare);

    for(z=0;z<=n-1;z++)
    {
        if(lwKomorkach[z+1]==lwKomorkach[z])
        {
            lKolizji++;
        }
    }

    cout<<endl<<lKolizji<<endl;
    gsl_rng_free (r);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 10^14 is much larger than what a normal integer could hold. You probably need an unsigned __int64. See integer limits here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/296az74e.aspx

Comment: n = 519150 is nowhere close to the interger limit and it doesn't work for me;< i tried to remane it to long, to double, none of this worked. I also tried unsigned, but still doesn't work for bigger n

Comment: @Sarah Stop doing this: `int lwKomorkach[n-1];` This is not standard C++.  Use `std::vector`, and I wouldn't be surprised if your problems go away.  You are using "variable length arrays", which is nonstanard, and more than likely, you're blowing out the stack using them.  Use standard C++, `std::vector`.

Comment: @Sarah [Please read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890468/segmentation-fault-because-of-the-array-size/40891655#40891655).  It not only explains in detail the issue with `n` being large, but also how to solve your own issues concerning boundary conditions using `at()`.  Also quit using `qsort` and use `std::sort`.

Comment: `int n = 519140;
int lwKomorkach[n];` --> might lead to stackoverflow....

Answer (score 3):

Your issues are two-fold.

1) You're using non-standard C++ syntax in declaring your arrays.

2) You're more than likely going out-of-bounds of the array when accessing it.

To solve the first issue, this line of code is not standard C++.

```
int lwKomorkach[n-1];
```

Arrays in C++ must be declared with a compile-time constant.  Also, if `n-1` is large, you are risking exceeding the amount of reserved stack space.

The way to alleviate this is to use `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>
//...
std::vector<int> lwKomorkach(n-1);
```

Once you have this, then to ensure you're not going out-of-bounds, you can use the `std::vector::at()` function to check the bounds:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    lwKomorkach.at(i) = floor(gsl_rng_uniform (r)/dlPrzedzialu)+1;
}
```

If `i` is out of bounds, you will get an `std::out_of_range` exception instead of a "crash" or worse, not getting a crash and believing your program is working correctly when it really isn't working correctly.  You should apply the same test in your other `for` loop.

Once you fix the boundary issues, then you can change the code from `at()` to using `[ ]`, since the boundary errors are solved.

The last issue is the usage of `qsort`.  Use `std::sort` instead.  The `std::sort` is easier to use (no casting all over the place), can be optimized by the compiler much more readily, and can work for any types (while `qsort` only works for POD or `C` compatible types).

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
std::sort(lwKomorkach.begin(), lwKomorkach.end());
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

by that

```
int lwKomorkach[n-1];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    lwKomorkach[i]=floor(gsl_rng_uniform (r)/dlPrzedzialu)+1;

}
```

you are trying to put n items into n-1 size array. I guess it didn't crash at low number just by chance.

And it gets even worse at second loop

```
for(z=0;z<=n-1;z++)
{
    if(lwKomorkach[z+1]==lwKomorkach[z]){lKolizji++;}
}
```

when z= n-1, you are trying to assign to lwKomorkach[n] while maximum index of lwKomorkach can be is n-2

Comment: There is no table[3] at your code. I am talking about array you defined by lwKomorkach[n-1].

Comment: How would it look corrected? I try to change it, but nothing works

Comment: Well, declare the array as int lwKomorkach[n]; and at second loop, instead of  z<=n-1, make z<n-1

Comment: i just did it and now it doesn't work even for small numbers:<

Comment: And if you are not doing it already, use a debugger to see your errors.

Comment: @t.m. The fist step is to not use variable length arrays to begin with.  The code is nonstandard C++.

Comment: I don't get any errors in both mine and your version. In mine it crashes at higher numbers, and your version crashes on every n value

Comment: @Sarah You crash on the high values of `n` since you didn't use standard C++.  Use `std::vector<int>` as I pointed out in my comment.

Comment: If you insist on not using std::vector, you may try declaring lwKomorkach[] outside of main function as global variable, In this case, It won't be allocated at stack.

Comment: @t.m. *you may try declaring lwKomorkach[] outside of main function* -- That still doesn't address the issue of variable length arrays.  No matter where you declare that array, if a variable is used to denote the number of entries, it is non-standard C++.

Comment: Yes, it seems n never changes in the program anyway you can use a definition for array size instead like #define ARRAY_SIZE 519140 and use it instead of n everywhere.

Comment: i don't really get how to use sort. vector<int> lwKomorkach(n-1); goes like this. How does sort go?

Comment: @Sarah I posted what to address in my answer.